# Internal error on trades API

Tags: horizon, trade

Why do I get an internal error when requesting this url?

https://horizon.stellar.org/trades?base_asset_type=native&counter_asset_code=MOBI&counter_asset_issuer=GA6HCMBLTZS5VYYBCATRBRZ3BZJMAFUDKYYF6AH6MVCMGWMRDNSWJPIH

But if I add `counter_asset_type` the error doesn't appear. In the docs `counter_asset_type` is marked as optional argument.

Answer (score 1):

Whether `counter_asset_type` is required or not, you should not be seeing an internal server error. As the error document states, this is the server's fault, not yours.

I took a quick look through the [issues list](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues) and couldn't see this listed (though I'm not ruling out the possibility that I've overlooked it), so I [raised it](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/466).